# HTML Input Multiple Tag

Tags: html, forms, multifile-uploader

I have a simple HTML form that I am building. I want to be able to added multiple files to submit with the form to upload. Everything I am reading online about HTML5 says that I am able to do this with the HTML5 Input Multiple tag. When I try this in any browser I get the standard Input with a type of file. When I inspect the DOM i see that it has only a single file in it's Files[0] attribute. Here is my form. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my HTML for the the form for uploading files:

```
<form method="post" action=upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" id="basicUploadFile" multiple >
</form>
```

Also. I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox, IE 11. Even going to the W3school.com demo doesn't seem to work in any of them for multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`files[0]` will show you the first file selected. `files` gives you a collection of the selected files, `files.length` gives you the number of files selected. So once you select more than one file if you `console.log(fileinput.files)` you'll see multiple files logged.

Comment: Thank you. I was a bit confused as to the structure of the Files object in the DOM. This helped a ton!

Comment: When I try to select the element using a jquery selector it doesn't seem to find .files Example; $("#basicUploadFile).files returns undefined.

Comment: @user2997301 `$("#basicUploadFile")` is a jQuery Object the files property is on the dom element. To expose the dom element from the jQuery object you can do `$("#basicUploadFile").get(0)` or `$("#basicUploadFile")[0]`. So get files do `$("#basicUploadFile")[0].files` or `$("#basicUploadFile").get(0).files` or even `$("#basicUploadFile").prop('files')`.

Comment: Still only showing a single item in that array. When I check the $_FILES on the PHP end I get the following array; 'basicUploadFile' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'splash-620x300.png' (length=18)
      'type' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php77CD.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 12428

Comment: That's a php issue, if you want fields to be treated as arrays in php the field name has to end in `[]`.

Comment: As in the name property of the input needs to be "basicUploadFile[]" or do I need to do soemthing with the $_FILES array that I am using? Also, thank you for all the help.

Comment: `the name property of the input needs to be "basicUploadFile[]"` yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo? There is a " missing before the upload.php

your form tag looks correct

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select#Multiple_file_selection

[edit]
If you are referring to the W3schools site, this works for me on Chrome and IE
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

TryIt site:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_multiple

Comment: Yes, caught the type afteer I posted the question. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="UploadedFiles" name="UploadedFiles[]" multiple>
 <input type="submit" value="SendFile">
</form>
```

in upload.php analize structure of array $_FILES ;)

good like!